# How to track deleted database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose my sql server 2008 with username(sa) and password(testpass),with a instance(mypc).

i am having two computer name system1 and system2. If i am deleting the any database then

how can i track from which system this desired database is deleted.

Comment: From your question, it's not clear to me if you need to know *after* or *during* the fact.

Comment: after deleating the database,it must have some logs that keep track of delated databse

Comment: don't forget to accept answers...

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a server audit to monitor all CREATE/ALTER/DROP DATABASE events.

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [DatabaseChanges]
    TO APPLICATION_LOG;

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseChangesSpec]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [DatabaseChanges]
    ADD (DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I've never run into this type of scenario before. What problem are you trying to solve?

You could monitor the filesystem where the database files are stored. Perhaps a command line application, or Windows service. When it detected database files to be deleted, you would then know.

Alternatively, from the client connection, you could try to connect to the database. If the login succeeded but database schema was not found, you could assume that the database had been deleted.

Comment: suppose two peoples in the company having rights to delete database,if one deleted the database(login are some for both person).then if i want to track who deleted the database

Comment: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Server_Audit_Examples_in_SQL_Server_2008#Server_Audit_Examples, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280479.aspx?